# Unable to fetch gradle dependency net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring-boot, grpc-java

I am using grpc springboot. I can download all dependencies apart from 'net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.12.0.RELEASE'.

Due to the I can't use annotation @GrpcService

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.37.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.37.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.37.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.5'
    implementation 'net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.12.0.RELEASE'
    compileOnly 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5'

}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What are the repositories that are configured in your build?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the ***install dependencies*** and ***reimport*** them.
If it doesn't work, close the **IDE** and open it again.